# Change default ordering of taxonomy terms - pre_get_terms

Tags: wp-query, terms, order, tax-query, menu-order

I wanted to change the default taxonomy terms order by its 'term_order' value instead of 'name' in admin side. So I tried something like below. But it doesn't work and php memory exhaust.

```
function uc_order_term( $wp_query ) {
    $wp_query->query(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'orderby' => 'term_order',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_terms', 'uc_order_term');
```

However in similar way I tried to sort posts by menu_order and it works.

```
function uc_order_post( $wp_query ) {

            $wp_query->set('orderby', 'menu_order');
            $wp_query->set('order', 'ASC');

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'uc_order_post', 1 );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am able to sort taxonomy terms by term_order using below snippets. But I am still seeking answer for the original question "How to do it using pre_get_terms".

```
function foo_tax_order($orderby, $args){

        return 't.term_order';
}
add_filter('get_terms_orderby', 'foo_tax_order', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Hey, have you tried something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41269101/wordpress-custom-taxonomy-query ?

Comment: @Pierre That link is for posts. I am asking about terms query.

Comment: I know, but I think it will work if you replace pre_get_posts by pre_get_terms and then use $query->set( 'orderby', 'term_order' ); within the function

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible with `get_terms_args`. The code only changes the order for categories.

```
function wp_custom_sort_get_terms_args( $args, $taxonomies ) {
    if ( isset( $taxonomies[ 'category' ] ) ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'term_order';
        $args['order']   = 'ASC';
    }
 
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'wp_custom_sort_get_terms_args', 10, 2 );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_terms_args/